# How to make different htaccess rewrite rules for root and for a subfolder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a directory structure like this:

```
root
root/en
```

I have a .htaccess in the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon\.ico  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show_article.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

This makes SEO friendly URLs.
(show_article.php generates the html output, but the URL is like this: root/title_of_the_article)

I'd like to clone the whole website into the root/en directory.

Now, with my .htaccess the output is this:

```
root/title -> root/title
root/en/title -> root/title
```

So I need to moodify my .htaccess to work like this:

```
root/title -> root/title
root/en/title -> root/en/title
```

I don't know how to do this, I tried several things today, but without any success.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this code in both `/.htaccess` and `/en/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show_article.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: My problem is that it seems, that the .htaccess in the root overwrites the one in the en/ directory.

Comment: No root .htaccess never overrides the one in sub-directory. Current directory's .htaccess always takes precedence. Does `show_article.php` exist in both `en` and in root? How are you testing it?

Comment: Yes, the show_article.php exists in both directories. Testing is simple, I type serverurl/en/title and got serverurl/title without the 'en'.

Comment: If URL is changing in browser then you have some other rule/code causing this as this rule is NOT doing any URL redirects